# There was a movie I saw in the late 60s/early 70s, people were trying to drill into a blue alien ship. I thought it was called “10,000 years to earth”

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I watched some trailers of 5 million years to earth, but that wasn’t it. And it didn’t have “journey” in the title. The blue ship-thingy was pretty tough to drill. Finding this movie is driving me nuts!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Would this have been a live-action show, or animated?  Where did you see it?

Comment: Please go through [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) of prompts to find other things to add. Like was it color? Black and white? How good were the special effects?

Comment: *20 Million Miles to Earth* matches title-wise and in terms of the time period, but it's in black and white, and I can't find a drilling scene.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots [Quartermass and the Pit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=033K233GIWs) has them trying to drill into a ship, so it's probably a good match.  It didn't really look blue, though.

Comment: @Cal - If you're the same person who just edited the deleted (non-)answer below, that isn't the proper way to confirm that an answer is correct. We can't even be sure that you're actually the same person, because you're now replying with a different account than the one you used to post the question. Please merge the two accounts by following the instructions at [this link](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts), so that you can formally mark user16145658's answer as accepted, and in doing so, automatically reward them with a small reputation boost.

Answer (score 18):

[Quatermass and the Pit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quatermass_and_the_Pit_(film))

> An attempt to open a sealed chamber in the object using a Borazon drill fails. However, a few moments later, a small hole is seen, though the drill operator, Sladden (Duncan Lamont), is certain he is not responsible. The hole widens to reveal the corpses of three-legged, insectoid creatures with horned heads. An examination of the creatures' physiology suggests they came from Mars. Quatermass and Roney note the similarity between their appearance and images of the Devil, while Quatermass believes the ship is the source of the spectral images and disturbances.

It's available to watch at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/quatermass-and-the-pit). I had never seen a color print.

[Quatermass And The Pit (1967) - Official Trailer - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=033K233GIWs).
The drilling scene is shown in part at around 40 seconds.

From Cal's second question that was accidentally posted [as a part of a deleted answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/261353/14850):

> It definitely was in color, live action and on TV. But that doesn’t mean it couldn’t have been in the theater. I’m sure my memory of the scene I’m thinking of in my mind has changed over the last 50-some years. But I’d bet my life the ship was futuristic looking, Royal blue, tough exterior, and a guy or team was walking on top of it, trying to figure out how to get in it. Definitely isn’t Quatermass…thanks for the suggestions though!!

You mean a blue spaceship like this?

[image]

The guy up on it had just got done heating it for 5 minutes with a oxygen-acetylene cutting torch without a mark or residual heat.

The drill scene had this supposedly hardest drill bit having no effect, until the spaceship reacted to the noise from the bit traveling through the hull.

I recall that it had been on television quite a few times, never saw it in a theater and didn't own or have access to a color TV at the time (hanging around less developed nations in the 70's).

Comment: a very sophisticated film for its time. or even for now.

Comment: Quatermass and the Pit was released as *10,000 years from Earth* in the USA and some asian markets.  I saw it under that name on MBC in Korea in about 1990.

Comment: Wow. Looking this up on Amazon Prime definitely leads down a schlock-film rabbit hole, to such classics as "Planet Of Dinosaurs", "They Came From Beyond Space", and "The Torture Chamber Of Dr. Sadism". (No, I'm not making this up). Looks like I know what I'm doing with my rainy Saturday afternoon... :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis-СлаваУкраїні RiffTrax riffed _The Torture Chamber of Dr Sadism,_ under the title _[Bloody Pit of Horror](https://www.rifftrax.com/bloody-pit-of-horror)_. It's pretty entertaining.